# Use variable to set name in JSON data with Firebase

Tags: javascript, firebase

I created this simple function to accept a "node" name and value, and update a Firebase accordingly:

```
function setAuctionSetting(node, value){
    dataRefSettings.update({
        node:value
    });
}
```

However, when I do this, in Firebase my "node" name is "node" instead of the value I am passing it. For example, I want to call:

setAuctionSetting('AuctionOn', 'True');

But this ends up storing:
node: "True"
Instead of:
AuctionOn: "True"

How can I use the value I am passing as the node name that I am storing to Firebase? Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

try this:

```
function setAuctionSetting(node, value){
    var obj = {};
    obj[node] = value;
    dataRefSettings.update(obj);
}
```

Comment: That works, but it also creates a node called "obj" and puts AuctionOn: "True" within that node. I'd like the same thing, but without that extra level of data structure.